# Drupal website All URL must https expert one URL (http://www.example.com/resourcesce-marking)

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https

In my drupal website need to do SSL for all the pages link https://wwww.example.com excerpt one page like http://www.example.com/resourcesce-marking

Answer (score 0):

Please edit index.php file and add new lines from below codes.

```
<?php

// Add new lines - Forwarding client to https protocol when it said your website on http protocol!
if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] != 'https') {
  header("Location: https://example.com");
  exit;
}
// End new lines

define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());

require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

// Add new line - Change $base_url to absolute URL
$base_url = 'https://example.com/';
// End new line

menu_execute_active_handler();
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir.